# Why Artisan commands boot service providers when executing

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

Let me first of all describe what structure I have. At my job we use Laravel 8, OpenServer as a local web server for each programmer, remote environments (which get the code from the local folders via PHPStorm sftp transferring) and MS SQL and Redis running on those remote environments.

So, we also have part of our app config inside database, that's why we created `ConfigServiceProvider` which checks whether the config exist in Redis or not. If it doesn't exist we pull it from the database, put it in Redis and set this config in config() helper. If it exist we just pull it from Redis and set it to config(), so then we can access those values everywhere in the app.

After that we created some components for application (basically some static classes which contain some business logic) and some of them should be instantiated only once for the whole app, so we created also `ComponentsServiceProvider` where we instantiate them. Obviously this service provider should be booted after `ConfigServiceProvider` because we need to use config() helper with values from db inside our instantiated components.

So, my problem was when I used any artisan command (e.g. `php artisan cache:clear`) it threw exception from my components. After a bit of investigation it turned out that in some functions I use the Carbon library which parses date that coming from `config(db_config.some_date)` helper which for some reasons doesn't return value (or maybe returns some garbage, I cannot debug it unfortunately) and parsing failed. Well, obviously artisan commands boot the whole application like as I open the app in a browser, right? When I just open it in a browser everything is fine and works like a charm, but when running artisan commands then I get such errors. I fixed them, just added default values anywhere where I use `config()` helper. But due to boot process I also getting another error - in .env we have `localhost` setting for redis host, because we transfer our code to remote environment and for the code Redis host is `localhost` obviously, but not for our local environments. So when I run artisan commands it also shouts at me that it cannot establish Redis connection (Of course you cannot, dummy). This problem I fixed with installing redis locally (not even using it, just for fixing the problem and it makes me sad).

My question is WHY artisan commands need to boot service providers for such operations like cache clear? Why it cannot just clear the necessary cache folders without boot app services? Can I change it somehow?
I switched to Laravel from the old CakePHP recently, so maybe I'm missing something what is obvious for experienced laravel programmers?

Comment: If you don't need code in your CLI that you register in your service provider, just exclude it in the CLI environment `if(!$this->app->runningInConsole()) { ....`. If you don't need code in a service provider to run AND if you're only binding your interface to the service container, [defer the service providers execution until its required](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers#deferred-providers)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thank you for the reply, it's a helpful trick. But for me it is still not completely clear why artisan do this "booting work" in commands which from my point of view doesn't even need the application to run